# How to display unique results from an array with two conditions

Tags: php, arrays, database, unique

In `$data` I have the following values:

**Result**

```php
[{"id":2,"author":"example@mail.com","id_orders":502},
{"id":2,"author":"example@mail.com","id_orders":503},
{"id":2,"author":"example@mail.com","id_orders":505},
{"id":3,"author":"second-example@mail.com","id_orders":502},
{"id":3,"author":"second-example@mail.com","id_orders":503},
{"id":3,"author":"second-example@mail.com","id_orders":505},
{"id":4,"author":"third-example@mail.com","id_orders":502},
{"id":4,"author":"third-example@mail.com","id_orders":503},
{"id":4,"author":"third-example@mail.com","id_orders":505}]
```

I want unique results for `id` and `id_orders`. I want 3 out of these 9 results. I have tried this, but it helps on one `id_orders` condition.

**PHP code**

```php
$result = json_decode($data, true);
$unique_array = [];
foreach($result as $element) {
   $hash = $element['id_orders'];
   $unique_array[$hash] = $element;
}
$data = array_values($unique_array);
```

Do you know how it can be different to make it work for two?

Comment: It is unclear what you're looking for or what `id_event_users` has to do with the array you presented. Can you specify what you consider to be _"unique results for id and id_orders"_?

Comment: Sorry, corrected. Thanks for your attention.

I want to get 3 results from this result:
{"id": 2, "id_orders": 502},
{"id": 3, "id_orders": 503},
{"id": 4, "id_orders": 505}.

Comment: It seems like an arbitrary choice to pair them up like that. What about situation where the number of unique values doesn't match (for example, 3 different ids, but 4 different order ids or vice versa)?

Comment: I wanted it that way. Thanks to this, I solved my previous uniqueness problem on the example of `id_event_users`:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66156653/display-unique-results-with-query-connecting-4-tables-in-laravel Here it's the same, but it's about `id_orders`. Now I have different `id_orders`, but too many results and I need the conditions.

Comment: So the algorithm would be first unique appearance of `id` gets paired with first unique appearance of `id_orders`, the second `id` with the second `id_orders` and so on?

Comment: In this case, yes. I want to try if it works as needed.

Comment: Well, that algorithm doesn't cover the case I've mentioned (where there is a different number of unique values for each of the indices). What would be the expected result then?

Comment: The created query in Laravel, which I posted in the link, generates a number of results that I can't control: if there is 1 opinion, it adds 1 result to `$data`, if 2 opinions are 4 results, if 3 opinions are 9 results, and so on. Here I gave an example with 3 orders - there should be 3 and there are 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by keeping track of the values that were already used. Disclaimer: this solution will only produce a clear result for cases where the number of unique values for both criteria is the same.

```php
$uniqueArray = [];
$usedValues = [
    'id' => [],
    'id_orders' => [],
];
foreach ($result as $element) {
    if (!in_array($element['id'], $usedValues['id']) && !in_array($element['id_orders'], $usedValues['id_orders'])) {
        $uniqueArray[] = $element;
        $usedValues['id'][] = $element['id'];
        $usedValues['id_orders'][] = $element['id_orders'];
    }
}
```

Basically, what's happening here is that we're using `$usedValues` to store all the unique values we've already used and comparing against it using `in_array`. When we iterate through the objects, any object with an `id` or `id_orders` that has already been used will be skipped. The pairings will be done in order of appearance in the array.

I've gone an extra mile to try and make this code a bit more generic:

```php
 * Finds elements with a unique combination of values under given keys.
 *
 * Assumes all elements in the array are arrays themselves and that the
 * subarrays have the same structure. Assumes subarray elements are not
 * objects (uses strict comparison).
 */
function uniqueCombination(array $arrayToFilter, array $keysToFilterOn): array
{
    if (empty($arrayToFilter) || empty($keysToFilterOn)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
            'Parameters of uniqueCombination must not be empty arrays'
        );
    }
    // get the keys from the first element; others are assumed to be the same
    $keysOfElements = array_keys(reset($arrayToFilter));
    $keysPresentInBoth = array_intersect($keysToFilterOn, $keysOfElements);
    // no point in running the algorithm if none of the keys are
    // actually found in our array elements
    if (empty($keysPresentInBoth)) {
        return [];
    }

    $result = [];
    $usedValues = array_combine(
        $keysPresentInBoth,
        array_fill(0, count($keysPresentInBoth), [])
    );
    foreach ($arrayToFilter as $element) {
        if (!isAlreadyUsed($usedValues, $element)) {
            $result[] = $element;
            foreach ($keysPresentInBoth as $keyToUse) {
                $usedValues[$keyToUse][] = $element[$keyToUse];
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

function isAlreadyUsed(array $usedValues, array $element): bool
{
    foreach ($usedValues as $usedKey => $usedValue) {
        if (in_array($element[$usedKey], $usedValue)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

In its core, this is the same algorithm, but made dynamic. It allows a variable number of keys to filter on (that's why they're passed separately as an argument), so the `$usedValues` array is created dynamically (using the first element's keys as its own keys, filled with empty arrays) and all the keys must be compared in loops (hence the separate function to check if an element's value had already been used).

It could probably be tweaked here or there as I haven't tested it thoroughly, but should provide satisfactory results for most structures.